# Calculated Filter for Fusion Map layer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, filter, google-fusion-tables, layer

I've used the Fusion layers Wizard to generate a map with three layers and three filters here: http://a-bc.co.uk/freq.html.

I'd really like 2 of the filters to be calculated from one of the others.  ie: if Filter 2 is set to 95.8, then Filter 1 would be 0.1 less (95.7) and Filter 3 would be 0.1 more (95.9).

The trouble is I have no idea on the syntax of the code written by the wizard!  I'm guessing I need to change the code in the snippet below - but how?  Any hints greatly appreciated!

```
function changeMap_0() {
      var whereClause;
      var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
      if (searchString != '--Select--') {
        whereClause = "'Frequency (MHz)' = '" + searchString + "'";
      }
      layer_0.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: "col11",
          from: "1jWzZOIbzzRZvc2S1HXX2yCi2lr-472_5_V96wqgI",
          where: whereClause
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need the 3 lists at all? When changing 1 list should force the change of the other 2 lists a single list would be sufficient. Furthermore: what if the 2nd list is set to e.g.  87.7 (the first list should then be set to 87.6, but this value is not inside the list)?

Comment: Hi Dr Molle - yes one list that automatically selected the F+0.1 and F-0.1 integers for the other two layers would be ideal - but Google Fusion layers Wizard does not give me the option to do that.

Comment: Good point on the non-existent numbers - in an ideal world they should all exist, if not then "hopefully" it would display nothing, or if necessary an error trap to say "display nothing".   trouble is, although I understand the concept of coding in general, I do not know Javascript syntax (if that's what this is written in!)

Comment: Hi all.  I've just had another go at this task, but I'm too much of a "coding-numpty" to work it out!  Can anyone help?   Basically I want to calculate the first and third filters from the middle value.  ie if the middle one is set to 95.8, I want the first filter to set to 95.7 and the third to 95.9.   After that we might also need an error trap in case that value does not exist in the list of values being searched in the Fusion table ( afew are missing).   Any help would be really, REALLY appreciated!